# How to organize a home page for my App using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a new project where I should implement a new application in an existing  system. Users will be able to access my app through an existing login page. Once they log in I will have all information available in my session variables. Link for my app is available for the users based on their credentials. Now I want to organize my home page. My question is should I use `iframe` to be my home page? Should I place everything else inside of the `iframe`? I don't have experience working with `iframes` and I'm not sure if this is the best option. Here is example of what I have:

```
<iframe src="Home.cfm" name="homeFrame" id="homeframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Here is my `Home.cfm` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainpage">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also i have included JQuery on my home page. I might have two more pages in this app. Is that the best place to include the library? Or that should be included on each page in the app?

Comment: do you have to use iframe?

Comment: I don't have to use iframe. I'm wondering what is the best thing to use and be compatible on laptop,tablet and mobile devices. At the same time what is the best and most in use now days. Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do something often depends on the specific requirements of the task at hand.

Comment: Why are you considering an iframe versus standard redirection from the login page? Reason for asking is iframes have their own set of quirks....

Answer (score 1):

If you add it in home page that is enough.Try like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainpage">
    //whatever you have already in this page.Using iframe you can display a separate document, including scrollbars and borders.
    <iframe src="Home.cfm" name="homeFrame" id="homeframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

default.js:

```
$(function(){
alert('success');
//your stuff
});
```

Comment: you are not looking like this? @espresso_coffee

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand your answer. Are you suggesting not to use iframe or?

Comment: you can use iframe.I updated the answer.Please see that @espresso_coffee

Comment: Should I have iframe inside the body or iframe should be warped around my entire page content?

Comment: you can use the iframe in inside body also and you can adjust with width and height

Comment: For the most part I'd try to avoid iframes unless the is a REALLY good reason.  I'd do somthing like:

    <div class="mainpage">
    <cfinclude template="Home.cfm">
    </div>